# Predefine Filters for PandasGUI

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandasgui

For several days now I've been trying to find a way to add filters to the PandasGUI call.
So far I have only managed to filter a dataset in advance and display the filtered record or display the whole dataset and apply each filter manually.
However, since multiple people are using the dataset, each using different filter options, I wanted to display all the filters used under the filter tab and each user can then enable or disable their filters.
Do any of you know of such a function or is this even possible?

Let's look at an example:
[image: example dataset]
Instead of specifying the 4 filters on the right side manually each time via the query expression, I would like to include them in the call. If now a user comes and wants to filter for diamonds over 1000$, he no longer has to enter the entire query manually, but only activate the corresponding field.

So far no search on the internet and reading the pandasgui docu has given any success.
I am also open to other GUIs that fulfill my needs.